# Build CakePHP3 query with field name as parameter

Tags: sql, cakephp-3.0

I want to build (for example) the following sql query where the position field of the matched data rows should be incremented by one:

```
UPDATE images SET position = position + 1 WHERE (position > 2 AND position <= 4)
```

I've tried to build the query with CakePHP 3's query builder:

```
$query->update()
 ->set(['position' => 'position + 1'])
 ->where(['position >' => 2])
 ->andWhere(['position <=' => 4])
 ->execute();
```

Due to the fact that position is an integer, CakePHP converts  the expression 'position + 1' to 0 and don't pass 'position + 1' to the sql query.

Is there a way to build this query with the CakePHP query builder or must I use a raw sql statement for this?

Comment: simply `set(['position  = position + 1']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the correct way to do it should be

```
$expression = new QueryExpression('position = position + 1');
$query->update()
    ->set([$expression])
    ->where(['position >' => 2])
    ->andWhere(['position <=' => 4])
    ->execute();
```

but I guess you could simply do

```
set(['position = position + 1']);
```

see the [manual](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#bulk-updates)